# Android offline location fetch

Tags: android, location, offline, fusedlocationproviderapi

Cannot able to fetch the location in offline mode using fused location provider client for lower version device like lollipop and  jellybean device.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please edit your question and provide [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your question

Answer (score 0):

You can get the GPS location from the mobile SIM, GsmCellLocation will provide you the coordinates from the nearest mobile tower.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation gsmCellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

    int cell_id = gsmCellLocation.getCid();
    int cell_lac = gsmCellLocation.getLac();

    Log.d("CellLocation", gsmCellLocation.toString());
    Log.d("GSM Location Code", String.valueOf(cell_lac));
```

:)